# How to display comma-separated values one by one inside a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagrid and inside the grid I have five columns. In one column, I am displaying comma-separated values which are unorganized. The gridview is like

```
     Col1          Col2          Col3                   Col4           Col5  
      1             a         [acvdfvd], [dfasfsd        20              10
                              dfdfs],[sdfdsf][sadsa
                              fsfesf],[adsdas],
                              [dsfsdfdf],[dfss]
      2             b             "                       30              20
```

Now, I want to show the values like this,

```
  Col1          Col2          Col3                   Col4           Col5  
   1             a          [acvdfvd],                 20              10
                            [dfasfsddfdfs],
                            [sdfdsf],
                            [sadsafsfesf],
                            [cxadsdas],
                            [dsfsdfdf],
                            [dfss]

      2             b             "                       30              20
```

This will at least be understandable. Please help me on how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to have a new line after each comma separated value. You can use string.Replace for this purpose with `Environment.NewLine`

```
string str = str.Replace(",", "," + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

After evey comma (,) add `<br />` tag. That will bring the next value to the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a <br/> tag after each comma.

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating that column of values? From your tags, if it is C#, you can append after the comma an Environment.NewLine

Comment: I am not doing it in c#. I am binding the values in aspx source page itself.

Answer (score 0):

use a template field.....like this

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="txt" Text='<%# Bind("Col3") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

at the back end add (break) tag after ,(comma)

here Col3 will have the values

```
 [acvdfvd],<br />[dfasfsddfdfs],<br />[sdfdsf][sadsafsfesf] etc
```

Hope it helps!!!!.

Comment: Could u pls explain how to do this? This is what I did. <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Influencing Factors" ItemStyle-CssClass="wrappable"  >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblinflufactors" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InfluencingFactors") %>'><br /></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle CssClass="wrappable" />
</asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Where should i add the break <br/> ?